# How do I populate a dropdown list with members of an Active Directory Group in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'd like to populate a dropdown list with names of members from an Active Directory group. All I can get it to do currently is display Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem so something is going wrong somewhere.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ManagementUsers = GetManagementUsers();

public static List<SelectListItem> GetManagementUsers()
{
    List<SelectListItem> _users = new List<SelectListItem>();
    PrincipalContext adServer = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAIN");

    GroupPrincipal managerGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(adServer, "Management Group");

    if (managerGroup != null)
    {
        foreach (Principal principal in managerGroup.GetMembers())
        {
            _users.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = principal.SamAccountName, Value = principal.SamAccountName });
        }
    }

    List<SelectListItem> ManagementUsers = _users;

    return ManagementUsers;
}
```

And then on my Razor Page:

```
<select id="manager" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-items="@(new SelectList(IndexModel.ManagementUsers))">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your razor page , change to use below code :

```
<select id="manager" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-items="@((List<SelectListItem>)IndexModel.ManagementUsers)">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

As @poke suggested , you can directly use `asp-items="@IndexModel.ManagementUsers"`

Comment: You shouldn’t need the explicit cast to `List<SelectListItem>` there. Just `asp-items="@IndexModel.ManagementUsers"` should work.